# Does Merlin in Le Morte d'Arthur have any kind of backwards aging or memory?

Tags: arthurian-legend, le-morte-darthur, thomas-malory

In T. H. White's [*The Once and Future King*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Once_and_Future_King) (1958), Merlyn ages backwards, remembering the future and constantly becoming younger himself. [An old answer on another SE site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15563/31394) claims that:

> This view of Merlin is canonical with the original written translation of the Arthurian cycle, ["Le Morte d'Arthur". In it, Merlin is said to "remember what is in our future", and to "have no knowledge of what is in our past".
>
> He physically does not age, and this is never explained, only mentioned. There is never any reference to his perception of speech and motion being backwards as well.

However, [others have expressed doubt](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/262198/where-does-the-aging-backwards-trope-originate#comment722477_262198) about whether this feature of Merlin can really be found in Malory's *Le Morte d'Arthur*.

**Does Malory's version of Merlin display any kind of "living backwards"?** Either in his memories or in anything physical? If so, where exactly is this stated?

Comment: It is a while since I read it, so comment not answer, but no, he doesn't.  His memories of the future aren't explained explicitly, all is deliberately vague.  I'll try to produce a proper answer shortly.

Comment: I agree with @Chenmunka - Merlin gives prophecies and interprets dreams. I don't see anything about "remembering the future"